# Android - Open Dialog from Fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, dialog

i´ve searched a lot and didn´t find any solution:

Is there any possibility to open a Dialog-window while the Fragment-window is open?
Maybe communicate through the MainActivity?

(i´m using kotlin)
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently faced a similar problem.
Here you should pay attention to how you are going to move into the dialog fragment.
Based on my personal experience, I can offer an exit via Navigation controller.
Here is a **very good** example
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/mad-skills-navigation-wrap-up-4e5733ecb107

Good luck!